# "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation already exists" for unique together constraint

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations

How can I list all uniqueness constraints on a table and delete any ones that conflict with my Django migrations?

Lots of other StackOverflow questions have asked about "relation already exist" errors, but this is specific to the uniqueness constraints. I do NOT want the usual recommended method of faking the migration `python manage.py migrate --fake`. I want to just delete the conflicting constraint so the migration can proceed normally.

I tried to add a unique together constraint, it worked fine locally, but caused a "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation already exists" error remotely. Specifically, I am getting an error like this.

```sql
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "api_mytable_myfield1_myfield2_cb8c1059_uniq" already exists
```

My migration file looks like this:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('api', '...'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
            name='mytable',
            unique_together={('myfield', 'myfield2')},
        ),
    ]
```

How can I make things work again? I am using Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please *don't* alter the databae manually. If you later migrate another database, it will produce the same problems. The idea of migrations is to create a database, without having to interact with the database manually.

A problem is that Django does not have a <s>`DeleteUniqueTogether`</s>, but only a [**`AlterUniqueTogether`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/migration-operations/#alteruniquetogether) and likely this will not change in the near future: `unique_together` should not be used anymore. Django has a [*constraint framework* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/constraints/).

Your `MyTable` thus should use:

```
class MyTable(models.Model):
    # ...

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=('myfield1', 'myfield2'),
                name='mytable_myfield1_myfield2_cb8c1059_uniq'
            )
        ]
```

If there is a specific reason why that is not possible, you should let the migration run the query:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('api', '...'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
            'ALTER TABLE mytable DROP CONSTRAINT mytable_myfield1_myfield2_cb8c1059_uniq;'
        ),
        migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
            name='mytable',
            unique_together={('myfield', 'myfield2')},
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: This is the better solution — to include it in the migration file itself. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can list the constraints on the table opening a Postgres shell and doing `\d mytable`. Once you have found the name of the constraint, you can delete it with something like:

```sql
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP CONSTRAINT mytable_myfield1_myfield2_cb8c1059_uniq;
```